# Suggestion how to capture the content of the google maps marker in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Hello I'm working with the android method `onInfoWindowClick`.

I need to press the event to get the data of that marker that are in the database, so far I just happen to pass on to the snippet the id and then get `marker.getSnippet()` and there I take the information.

What I need is to indicate if the place is open or closed. If it is open, I open a dialog, if it is closed, it should indicate that it is closed with a Toast. The variables boolean where I have to verify if it is open or I have closed them in firebase.

if I use `marker.getId` return the id of the m5 marker, which does not link to my database any id to be able to compare and obtain the status of local

```
gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(ArrayGMaps.get(i).getNamePlaces())
                    .snippet("MY PLACES." +" "+ ArrayGMaps.get(i).getIdPlaces())
                    .icon(icon)
                    .position(place));
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(place).zoom(11).build();
            gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Event to click

```
@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

    MyplacesList = new ArrayList<>();
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String savedList = preferences.getString("MyGoogleMaps","");
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<Myplaces>>(){}.getType();
    MyplacesList = gson.fromJson(savedList,type);

    for (int i = 0; i < MyplacesList.size(); i++) {

          String id =  marker.getSnippet();
          String id2 = MyplacesList.get(i).getIdPlaces();
        if  (id.equals(id2)) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Click: "+ marker.getSnippet() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Solution. Was to compare with latitude and longitude.

```
@Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker)  {
    double lLat1 = marker.getPosition().latitude;
    double lLong2 = marker.getPosition().longitude;

    MyplacesList = new ArrayList<>();
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String savedList = preferences.getString("MyGoogleMaps","");
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<Myplaces>>(){}.getType();
    MyplacesList = gson.fromJson(savedList,type);

    for (int i = 0; i < MyplacesList.size(); i++) {
        Double SLat = Double.parseDouble(MyplacesList.get(i).getMyLatitud());
        Double SLong = Double.parseDouble(MyplacesList.get(i).getMyLongitud());

        if (SLat == lLat1 &&  SLong == lLong2) {

            if (MyplacesList.get(i).myOpen.equals("true")) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Abierto: " + MyplacesList.get(i).myOpen, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Cerrado: " + MyplacesList.get(i).myOpen, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

    }

}
```